# DataEnter of DataGridView is hit twice when opening the form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to run an expensive database query every time when a user enters a row in the data grid view. However, the event `RowEnter` is hit twice when opening the form?

```
private void DGV_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Assign the event handler in the form's load event.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void DGV_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.ActiveControl != DGV)
         return;
}
```